# Add bounty details to Community Data Dump

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, data-dump

I was looking at a [recent question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27307/why-do-i-always-have-to-accept-an-answer-at-the-end-of-the-bounty-period) on bounties, and I wanted to use StackQL to prove that questions with bounties get more views and answers on average than questions without, and quantify just how much based on the bounty level.  However, it turns out that there's no information on bounties in data set. Please add BountyAmount (int) and BountyAwarded (DateTime) columns to the posts table in the data.

**Edit**:
On further reflection, there's no need for the BountyAwarded column.  Any question with a BountyAmount > 0 and a non-null AcceptedDate had the bounty awarded on that date.  But we do still need the BountyAmount column.

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110182/158912

Answer (score 4):

We will include BountyAmount in the latest export.  VoteTypeId = 9 is BountyClose, so if there is a corresponding BountyAmount attribute then a bounty was awarded.  It is possible for a bounty close to result in 0 in the case where the person who created the bounty accepts an answer that they posted.