# Why is there a bounty, when an answer is already accepted?

Tags: discussion, bounties

The Question is: [Catching exceptions in destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963580/catching-exceptions-in-destructors)

I asked a question in 2013, got some good answers, and accepted one.

Now this week (early 2018), I got a notice that someone else had put a bounty on my question.

But I've already accepted an answer.   How is the bounty meant to be collected if I'm not going to change my mind, and the bounty-provider can't change the accepted answer??

Comment: Because the new bounty can be assigned to any answer by the person who put it there. Whether or not it's the accepted answer, a new one or a different existing one doesn't matter

Comment: The relevant info is already contained in the FAQ, so this is a duplicate. Please note that it's policy to close questions as duplicates of FAQs if all of the information being asked for is in the FAQ. This is to direct all users to the canonical source containing the relevant info.

Comment: Your accept of an answer is the _least_ indication of commonly usefulness.

Answer (score 5):

Bounties are *not* in any way linked to the selected answer. In *this* case - they have a similar question, are unhappy with the current answers and want more attention. They can select something other than the selected answer for the bounty once its posted.

You can also post a bounty cause an answer was just that awesome. Not the case here.

As someone who didn't post the bounty... well, you have no direct say in who gets it.

Comment: He might be reading the really old blog post which describes the old system of how bounties were strictly tied to accepting an answer.

Comment: I don't ever remember that being the case.

Comment: Additionally, only the OP could start one, and there was an extra +50 bonus rep added. The system was changed to the current way in 2010-11 or so; this original system was implemented in 2009.

Comment: Yeah, what @Ano says is right, as that's what's described in the [very first revision of the bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/16067/1), with the change described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/54292/323179). (However I doubt that's why the OP is confused.)

Comment: @Laurel The blog post describing the old behavior is still up.